# serve 2 Angular apps using tomcat

Tags: angular, spring-mvc

I'm trying to load 2 angular applications from same port .
The First app that was already deployed and it is working fine .
The Folder `WebContent` has `app , node_modules , common` .
Now i have added a folder App2 inside WebContent folder . App2 is built using angular 4 and angular cli . i ran `ng build` and copied everything from `dist` folder to App2 . But on running the second App , i get unexpected token < in `inline.bundle.js` and other bundles also.
How can i solve it ?

App2.jsp:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Verification App</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the `app2.jsp` is being loaded but not `bundle.js` files

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered this (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml) while `ng build` ?

Comment: Have tried everything :( no Luck. @Yatinpatel